# Is Google and SEO the reason for Stack Overflow's strict content guidelines?

Tags: discussion

I spotted a post on Medium about 5 minutes ago regarding Stack Overflow's strict guidelines on content. The article speculates that it's related to SEO and a decrease in revenue for Stack Overflow after the Panda update.

Is there any truth to this? The article can be read here: https://medium.com/@jamesjefferyuk/the-real-reason-for-the-decline-of-stackoverflow-10b0132a13b1#.mncz099a3

A quote that struck my attention, and seems to make sense:

> The amount of content on Stack Overflow is huge. After the Panda update Joel and Jeff would have seen a significant decrease in traffic, which in turn means a significant drop in revenue. A lot of content on the site would have been pushed down the SERP (Search Engine Results Page).
>
> What’s the best way to improve this situation? Obviously it’s to increase the quality of content submitted by users. They do this by using moderators to enforce content guidelines.

Could anyone comment on this?

Comment: eh, i don't think our moderation is any more strict now than it was before said update.

Comment: The author of the article appears to know very little about SO

Comment: The rules are just to make the site higher quality. That's been the goal from the start- A high quality repository of questions and answers. So what's correct is that the reason the guidelines are so strict is high quality- But not because of SEO. In fact, there was a question about whether the site was hurt by the Panda update when it happened, IIRC, and the guidelines were just as strict _before_ that update.

Comment: This is embarrassingly misinformed.  Moderators don't normally set content guidelines.  The community does.

Comment: Wow, conspiracy theory meets anti-Stack Overflow rant.

Comment: If that article would be a post on SO I would downvote it. So much wrong information in that article.

Comment: You'd expect as much from someone who provides such brilliant insights as ["Jeff is a douche."](https://medium.com/@jamesjefferyuk/ive-been-using-so-since-the-very-beginning-i-ve-had-multiple-different-accounts-over-the-years-ae86b41bf6f7#.kr27586w8)

Comment: Can we please stop taking these posts seriously? I don't think there have been *any* yet that aren't a personal rant based on false assumptions.

Comment: @Kendra that makes sense. It was the image in the article that got me because it seemed to match up with the Panda update. Don't get me wrong, I've been caught out by posts being put on hold ... but generally that's just because I've been lazy and I deserve my post to be put on hold.

Comment: @BradLarson Made all the more entertaining by the fact that Jeff hasn't worked on SO for several years now...

Comment: @BugHunterUK The number of posts being closed goes up over time because the total number of questions being asked is going up over time.  Some localized increases are also related to improved tools/features for ensuring that close-worthy questions actually get closed, or in some cases, changes in the amount of close worthy questions posted.  The actual quality standards for the site have changed *very* little over time, and when they do change, it tends to be slowly, so you don't see it manifested in graphs like that.

Comment: @BugHunterUK If memory serves, Fall 2012 was when the revamped review queues rolled out, so that is likely the explanation for the increase you see in closed questions at that time.  Essentially the site improved the tools it exposed to users interested in reviewing posts.  Note that that change had been in the works for over a year; it wasn't a response to Google changing an algorithm.

Comment: Oh, yea, I remember back in 2011 when SE pulled all the mods in and told them that short questions were no longer allowed because they result in bad SEO.  That totally happened.

Comment: @BigHunterUK Just remember that correlation does not necessarily mean causation. :) That the image matches the poster's claim isn't surprising- Of course they would want an image that backs up what they're saying. A lot of what's in that post, though, is just plain wrong. Just because a question is short does not mean it will be closed- So long as it is on-topic and has what's needed to answer it. Just because a question is hard to answer also does not mean it will be closed, it's just a tough question. I believe I myself have questions fitting one or the other criteria.

Comment: @Kendra and Servy thanks for the explanations they are very helpful. I feel foolish for being baited now.

Comment: @BigHunterUK At least you thought to confirm the post rather than just believe it and going on a hate quest against Stack Overflow. The point of posts like that _is_ to hate on Stack Overflow and try to show what's wrong with the site. Sadly, most of the posts against Stack Overflow are filled with falsehoods and misinformation, usually because the poster just does not understand the site as they think they do. And don't worry about the downvotes on your post here- I'm pretty sure they're just in disagreement with the premise of Stack Overflow only wanting quality for SEO reasons.

Comment: The post has nonsense right there, in the quote that struck your attention. By Google standards Stack Overflow content is not even remotely huge. Google searches and indexes billions pages - to them searching and ranking [current 10 millions questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/10m-questions-milestone/info) wouldn't be much different from 20 millions or 40 or 100. From perspective of _feeding Google_ Joel and Jeff would rather stick to keeping them all and relying on Google relevance ranking to pick the stuff worthy to show in search results.

Comment: I love that first graph's caption: *The number of questions closed as a result of Google’s Panda update*. Ummm... what? Was there a new close reason "Because Panda" that I missed?

Comment: I was on a mobile device earlier when I saw this, but I managed to read the rest of the article.  All I can really think is, I'm not going to miss this person from Stack Overflow, and I can only be happy for them in their finding a site that works for them.

Comment: I googled his name and it appears he is a convicted hacker. Confused!

Comment: "Thin content" indeed...

Comment: anything which titles itself as *"the real reason for..."* is generally full of crap

Comment: I'm not sure I trust someone who thinks the moderators are responsible for quality, and who gives a fancy acronym ("SERP") to search results.

Comment: @ArtOfCode True on the first, but SERP is a real thing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, SO's high quality standards and the motivation to improve the quality of posts on the site isn't new, or a response to a change in Google.  The site was *founded* with the goal of creating high quality questions with high quality answers, specifically because those founders were just so frustrated at having to deal with other sites just being full of crap; they wanted to create a place that was different.  That happened *years* before the change in Google's algorithm that the article refers to.

The entire reason that SO got as big as it has, and that it has maintained it for as long as it has, is precisely because it *does* have those high quality standards for posts.  Arguing that SO would be doing much better if it removed/dropped its quality standards would be to say that it should be doing what all of the competitors *that SO has completely dominated for years* kept doing unsuccessfully.

The article argues that people are leaving the site because of its strict quality standards.  This true.  This has always been true.  There are, and have always been, people that aren't interested in, or capable of, producing quality content, and as such, find themselves not enjoying participating in a site that demands quality contributions.

However, there are a *huge* number of people that *are* interested in quality contributions, both in consuming it and providing it.  That is SO's target audience.  In particular, the subject matter experts for the various topics that are in scope in SO tend to be people that are more than happy to answer great questions, but just aren't interested in sifting through piles of crappy questions to find them, and who are also interested in ensuring all that answers (not just their own) to questions are correct, well written, and *useful*.  The whole model of SO has been to attract *these* users to the site, and as long as those users want to participate on SO, others will follow.  People with questions that they want answered will come here, because that's where the people who can provide the best answers will be.

Comment: a reference supporting point made in last paragraph is [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/): "we're determined to keep question quality high, even at the cost of refusing a little sand. It's true that you can't have Q&A; without questions, but having the wrong sorts of questions is far more dangerous. The fastest way to kill any Q&A; site is to flood it with low-quality questions... Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?"

Answer (score 3):

I think the final section of that blog post says it all:

> A Message To The Mods
>   Stop wasting your time building reputation and points. It has little value and will not score you the best job, or the best clients. It’s meaningless.

Not sure he understands why I like being a mod - it certainly isn't to get a job or clients.

> Instead of helping to line the pockets of the owners — who clearly have no regard for the programming community — your time would be better spent innovating new ideas. That’s what will land you success and money.

I have sufficient success and money. And I don't think mods are supposed to be innovative, as such...

> StackExchange is now permanently added to my /etc/hosts file. I have found better alternatives such as: IRC, Discord, Slack, Reddit and Quora.

I'm guessing the blog poster sees things as a way to money, success, better job, better clients and SE didn't give him these. For those who enjoy giving some of their experience to help others it is very rewarding. So he is better off not using SE, and SE is better off as a redirect in his /etc/hosts

Oh, and to answer the question - I haven't seen anything change because of any move to Panda or other system. The only changes I have seen are because of community pressure, or because of increases in junk posts.

Comment: I think this is one of his profiles. I've found a few more but can't confirm: http://stackoverflow.com/users/256409/james-jeffery. From research he's also a convicted hacker https://www.theguardian.com/world/2012/apr/13/bpas-hacker-james-jeffery-jailed ... I'm not sure if these two people are the same. I'm trying to find accounts where he moderated. If he ever has.